# Вопрос по лицензированию Microsoft

Tags: windows, лицензирование

У меня есть тонкие клиенты на Linux, которые работают в терминальном режиме на Windows 2003. Microsoft меня уверяет, что я должен приобрести на них Core CAL, для подключения к серверу терминалов.

Естественно, лицензии для терминалов у меня куплены в необходимом количестве. Так + еще ко всему, они требует теперь купить Windows Pro-Upgrade, для терминальных клиентов мотивируя это тем, что согласно договора EA, я имею право лицензировать компьютеры только двумя позициями указанными в стандартном договоре от 2013 года. Там указано, что один из базовых продуктов включает в себя:

1. Windows ProDesktop
2. Windows Upgrade + Core CAL

---

Требуют потому что тонкий клиент попадает под определение «компьютер», и поэтому мы должны его лицензировать согласно этого определения по двум вышеуказанным типам базовых продуктов:

- Windows ProDesktop
- Windows Upgrade + Core CAL

Подключаюсь с помощью линуксовой программы *R-Desktop*.

Comment: @tutankhamun Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Укажите в чем именно состоит вопрос

Comment: Еще раз повторю: Почему от вас требуют лицензировать рабочие станции? Другими словами: Почему на рабочие станции вам навязывают Windows? Какой у вас договор? Software Assurance?

Comment: Ну согласно EA мы должны лицензировать рабочие станции под управлением Windows - это мне понятно. Но мне не понятно, почему на тонкие клиенты мы должны это делать. Договор Enterprise Agremeent с SA

Comment: @SaintPadre Ну тогда вы сами сделали свой выбор. Насколько я помню, по этому договору вы __обязаны__ лицензировать __весь__ парк вычислительной техники продуктами Microsoft, в одной из указанных комплектаций

Comment: Да я и сам это помню, так как даже проходил обучения пару лет назад. Но так же я помню, есть возможность не лицензировать какие-то устройства. Вот и хотел бы получить ответ на этом сайте. Попадаю ли я под возможность не лицензировать парк тонких клиентов работающих на Linux и в терминальном режиме подключающихся к Windows Server 2003.